# How to filter out '&nbsp' in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to detect if the selected element contains &nbsp only.

For example:

```
if('td').is(':empty'){
   //do something...
}
```

The above codes would work if `<td><td>` but not `<td>&nbsp</td>`.

What is the best way to filter out the `&nbsp`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could trim the string representation:

```
if ($('td').text().trim() == ""){
   //do something...
}
```

Admittedly, I'm making the rather bold assumption here that in general you don't want any table cell elements devoid of text, regardless of whether this is a case of `<td> </td>` or `<td><span></span></td>`.

If the second example is a false positive for your purposes, you can use a stricter version, like so:

```
var td = $('td');
if ((td.children().length == 0) && td.text().trim() == ""){
   //do something...
}
```

This ensures the `td` is not considered a match if it has nodes other than text nodes, regardless of whether it is devoid of text.

Answer (score 5):

```
if ($('td').html() == '&nbsp;')
```

Comment: I think the OP really wants to match any variation of empty - ie. either actually empty, or containing only white-space. This only matches literally a single &nbsp;